# How to use boost::optional

Tags: c++, boost, boost-optional

I am trying to use [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) as below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/optional.hpp>

struct myClass
{
   int myInt;
   void setInt(int input) { myInt = input; }
   int  getInt(){return myInt; }
};

boost::optional<myClass> func(const std::string &str)
{
   boost::optional<myClass> value;
   if(str.length() > 5)
   {
      // If greater than 5 length string. Set value to 10
      value.get().setInt(10);
   }
   else if (str.length() < 5)
   {
      // Else set it to 0
      value.get().setInt(0);
   }
   else
   {
      // If it is 5 set the value to 5
      value.get().setInt(5);
   }

   return value;
}


int main()
{
   boost::optional<myClass> v1 = func("3124");
   boost::optional<myClass> v2 = func("helloWorld");
   boost::optional<myClass> v3 = func("hello");

   if (v1)
       std::cout << "v1 is valid" << std::endl;
   else
       std::cout << "v1 is not valid" << std::endl;

   if (v2)
       std::cout << "v2 is valid" << std::endl;
   else
      std::cout << "v3 is not valid" << std::endl;

   if (v3)
      std::cout << "v3 is valid" << std::endl;
   else
      std::cout << "v3 is not valid" << std::endl;

  return 0;
 }
```

I get following error

> prog.exe:
>   /usr/local/boost-1.55.0/include/boost/optional/optional.hpp:631:
>   boost::optional::reference_type boost::optional::get() [with T =
>   myClass; boost::optional::reference_type = myClass&]: Assertion
>   `this->is_initialized()' failed.

Presumably, the optional variable is not initialized properly. How to do it the correct way?

EDIT:: Got some very good answers, just couple of more questions 1. Is it a good idea to use `make_optional` at the end of `'func'` function and return it? Also 2. I was thinking of assigning `boost::none` to emphasize that I have no value to assign and that's why `boost::none`. But not sure if that is valid?

Comment: Call `value.reset(myClass())` before calling `setInt`

Comment: Looking at the documentation, `reset` seems to be deprecated and you should use the assignment operator instead.

Comment: Why are you using `optional` here at all? You obviously never want to get an empty value so it makes no sense to have it here.

Comment: It is just a toy example. I know it's bad but I did not want to spend too much time forming the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A default-constructed `boost::optional` is empty - it does not contain a value, so you can't call `get()` on it. You have to initialise it with a valid value:

```
boost::optional<myClass> value = myClass();
```

Alternatively, you can use an [in-place factory](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/detailed_semantics.html#reference_optional_constructor_factory) to avoid copy initialisation (but the copy will most likely be elided anyway); however, I have no experience with that, so I can't provide an example.

---

As a side note, you can use `->` in place of `get()`, like this:

```
value->setInt(10);
```

But that's just a matter of stylistic preference, both are equally valid.

Comment: Exactly, alternatively you could use `value.reset(myClass())` as well.

Comment: I thought reset has been deprecated?

Comment: @polapts To make an `optional` empty again, simply assign into it: `value = boost::none;`.

Answer (score 14):

> How to do it the correct way?

```
boost::optional<myClass> func(const std::string &str)
{
    if(str.length() > 5)
        return myClass{10};
    if(str.length() < 5)
        return myClass{0};
    return myClass{5};
}
```

As a side note, this code doesn't need boost::optional, because there is no code branch that returns an empty object (it is semantically equivalent to returning a myClass instance).

To return an empty optional, use this:

```
boost::optional<myClass> func(const std::string &str)
{
    if(str.length() > 5)
        return myClass{10};
    if(str.length() < 5)
        return myClass{0};
    return boost::none; // return empty object
}
```

Idiomatic client code (don't pre-initialize your values):

```
int main()
{
    if (auto v1 = func("3214"))
        // use *v1 to access value
        std::cout << "v1 is valid" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "v1 is not valid" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For the empty optional, you can just `return boost:none;`

Answer (score 9):

Two easy approaches:

```
boost::optional<myClass> func(const std::string &str)
{
  boost::optional<myClass> value;
  if(str.length() > 5) // If greater than 5 length string. Set value to 10
    value = 10;
  else if (str.length() < 5) // Else set it to 0
    value = 0;
  else // If it is 5 set the value to 5
    value = 5;

  return value;
}

boost::optional<myClass> func(const std::string &str)
{
  if(str.length() > 5) // If greater than 5 length string. Set value to 10
    return 10;
  else if (str.length() < 5) // Else set it to 0
    return 0;
  else // If it is 5 set the value to 5
    return 5;
}
```

note that returning an `optional` from a function that never returns an empty optional is a bad idea.

`optional` behaves like a pointer on read access -- you can only *read* the value from it if you have already verified there is something there to read.  You can check if there is something to read by doing `bool something_to_read = opt;`.

You can, however, write to it whenever.  If there is nothing there, it creates something.  If there is something there, it overwrites it.

`.get()` is a reading, not a writing, operation.  (it "reads" the reference)  It is only safe to use when the `optional` is engaged and has data.  Confusingly, you can write to the "read access" `.get()` return value, as it is a non-const reference.

So maybe "read" and "write" are bad words to use.  :)

It is sometimes helpful to think of optional as a value-and-pointer mixed together.  There is a possibly null pointer to an owned buffer of memory that may, or may not hold a copy of the type.

If the pointer inside the optional is null, then the buffer is uninitialized.  If it points at the buffer, then the buffer is initialized.

`.get()` dereferences that pointer and returns the resulting reference *without* checking.  `=` checks the pointer, if it is null, it does a copy-construct from the rhs into the buffer and sets the pointer.  If not, it just assigns to the buffer.

(The pointer is conceptual: usually implemented as a `bool` flag).

I find using `*optional` to be better than `optional.get()`, as the "you must check before you dereference" is more obvious with the dereference operator.

Comment: Your second function still declares an (unused) `value`. On a stylistic remark, I would replace the `if` and three `return`s by a single `return` with a conditional expression.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You get no extra points for putting 2 conditionals on one line.  Fixed the wasted `value`, copy-pasta caught me!

Comment: In my books you definitely do, since it makes the code more readable. Compare yours with mine: https://gist.github.com/klmr/9391807.

Comment: @KonradRudolph wait, what, are you serious? I would probably curse when I saw that code.

Comment: @sehe Absolutely serious. I maintain that this his *vastly* more readable than Yakk’s code: it puts the emphasis squarely where it belongs: on the expression value, rather than the decision making logistics (`if…` statements). It’s what any functional language mandates anyway, it’s pervasive in my code base, and, might I remark, it’s also much shorter (not so much now that Yakk has removed the redundant braces, but still).

Answer (score 1):

```
boost::optional<myClass> func(const std::string &str)
{
    boost::optional<myClass> value; //not init is invalid
    if(str.length() > 5)       // If greater than 5 length string. Set value to 10
        value = 10;
    else if (str.length() < 5) // Else set it to 0
        value = 0;

    return value;
}


v1 is valid
v2 is valid
v3 is not valid
```

according to boost,optional default ctor will create an optional obj as invalid

```
optional<T> def ; //not initalize with a obj T
assert ( !def ) ;
```